# Update values of array if present in other array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array `$a`:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [param] => banana
        [value] => yellow
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [param] => lemon
        [value] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [param] => apple
        [value] => 18
    )
```

... and array `$b`:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [param] => banana
        [value] => brown
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [param] => orange
        [value] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [param] => lemon
        [value] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [param] => pear
        [value] => green
    )
```

Array `$c` should be a copy of `$a`, but, if `$b` contains certain params that are present in `$a`, the values from `$a` should be update with those from `$b`.

So `$c` would become:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [param] => banana
        [value] => brown
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [param] => lemon
        [value] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [param] => apple
        [value] => 18
    )
```

Any tips?

Comment: use `$a =  array_column($a, null, 'param');` and $b in the same way. After, the task will be trivial

Comment: Only trivial to some I'm affraid :). Should I use foreach to go through array $a? If so, how can I define if the key is present in $b?

Comment: @binoculars I updated my answer. Once have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array-map](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-map.php) with multiple arrays,

```
$c = array_filter(array_map(function ($a1, $b1) {
    if ($a1['param'] == $b1['param']) {
        $a1['value'] = $b1['value'];
        return $a1;
    } else {
        return $a1;
    }

}, $a, $b));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UAdtj)

**EDIT**

```
$bData = array_column($b,'value','param'); // param as key and value as value
foreach($a as &$v){
    $v['value'] = ($bData[$v['param']] ?? $v['value']); // php 7+   
    //or $v['value'] = (!empty($bData[$v['param']]) ? $bData[$v['param']] :   $v['value']);    // php 5.6 or previous

}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/G7O2p)

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [param] => banana
            [value] => brown
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [param] => lemon
            [value] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [param] => apple
            [value] => 18
        )

)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the same keys will be on the same positions? It's a strange approach

Comment: Unless we see more precision from OP. I have something in my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as @splash58 mentioned, this only works if the keys are on the same position, which isn't necessarily the case. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $a = ['banana' => 'yellow', 'apple' => 3, 'lemon' => 18];

    $b = ['banana' => 'brown', 'orange' => 3, 'lemon' => 4];

    $a_keys = array_keys($a);

    $c = $a;

    foreach ($a_keys as $key) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $b)){
            $c[$key] = $b[$key];
        }
    }
```